# Regex not filtering by the given criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I wanted to find whether the given word does not contain < > : | ". So i used the following javascript code block to find it. But it accepts all the values which has those characters also without.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chkResult').click(function() {
        $('#resultDiv').text(/[^:<>\|"]+/.test($('#dataText').val()));
    });
});​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d7uSA/37/ i have tried in this link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set regex to test your string from the beggining to the end with `^` and `$`:

```
/^[^:<>\|"]+$/.test($('#dataText').val())
```

Otherwise test passes if tested string contains at least one char that does not match your group.

Comment: Do you know why such behavior if not anchored? Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just anchor the regex:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chkResult').click(function() {
        $('#resultDiv').text(/^[^:<>\|"]+$/.test($('#dataText').val()));
//                      here__^    here__^
    });
});​
```